# How would a frequentist solve this?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, posterior, frequentist

I think i understand what bayesian viewpoint is and what frequentist viewpoint is. But i always feel like i am missing something. I think there is a blind spot. so as an attempt :-   Can somebody explain how would a frequentist solve this?

Suppose there is a mixed school having 60% boys and 40% girls as students. The girls wear trousers or skirts in equal numbers; the boys all wear trousers. An observer sees a (random) student from a distance; all the observer can see is that this student is wearing trousers. What is the probability this student is a girl? [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability)

I do not think given just this much a frequentist can solve this. But, I don't know

btw if a frequentist cannot solve this why have i not heard Bayesian interpretation touted louder than frequentist interpretation. It has always been 'it depends on you whom you want to be.'

Comment: Yours is a probability problem, which can be solved by bayes' theorem. There is nothing "Bayesian" about bayes' theorem, it is just a theorem of probability theory equally valid for frequentists and bayesians (and many others ...)

Comment: would not a frequentist say it is a guy since, (parameter  = (girl or guy). likelihood(guy/trouser = 1, likelihood(girl/trouser) = 0.5. MLE)?

Comment: No, (girl or guy) would not be a parameter! Here it would be a random variable, and the question could be treated as prediction, not estimation.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right about everything